# Can I restore a lost Chrome session?

Tags: google-chrome, restore, session, recovery, session-restore

My chrome crashed on me and the restore previous session button didn't work. Is there a way to restore previous session? I had 4 windows with different tabs opened through days and they were saved fine before. I tried installing [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko/related) after the crash so it didn't have data, and [Chrome_sessions from Github](https://github.com/aljgom/chrome_sessions) but it also didn't saved me. I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Session Buddy only works if you install it BEFORE you lose a session it does nothing after the fact.  If the session data is gone and cannot be recovered, and it seems you have attempted that, then you are out of luck. Once the data is deleted, or is never created in a case like yours, the session CANNOT be recovered.

Answer (score -1):

After a crash you might be able to find your previously open tabs under the history. In the history menu you might see something like Restore N tabs.